# OpenGL optimizing skybox rendering

Tags: opengl, skybox, zbuffer, depth-testing

I'm learning how to draw skybox using cubemaps from the following [resource](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Cubemaps).

I've got to the part where he talks about how we can optimize the rendering of the skybox. I get that instead of rendering the skybox first, which will result in `width*height` of your viewport fragments to be calculated and then only to be overdrawn by other objects, it's best to draw it last and fake its depth value to be `1.0f` by assigning the `gl_Position` of the skybox vertex shader to `gl_Position = pos.xyww` essentially making each `gl_FragCoord.z` equals to `1.0f` due to perspective division.

Now after we get a skybox with each of its fragments have maximum depth value of `1.0f` he changes the depth function to `GL_LEQUAL` instead of `GL_LESS`.

Here's where I got a little bit confused.

If we render the skybox last and have its depth values equal to `1.0f` why do we need to change the depth function to `GL_LEQUAL`? Wouldn't it be sufficient to have it set to `GL_LESS` because if we render every other object in the scene it depth value will probably be less than `1.0f` so it'll write its value to the `z-buffer` a value less than `1.0f`. Now if we set the depth function for the skybox to `GL_LESS` it will then only pass the fragments with depth value of less than what is actually in the `z-buffer` which will probably only pass fragments that other objects are not covering, so why do we need the `GL_LEQUAL`?

Comment: I think this is a bad tutorial to follow, using cube geometry and a VAO is an extreme overkill for a screen-space effect, see for example https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-skybox.html. Also, drawing the skybox first instead of last allows you to skip the framebuffer's color and depth clear, which I would profile heavily before calling one of both options a performance improvement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you initially cleared the framebuffer at the start of the frame, you probably did so to a value of 1.0f. So if you want to draw the skybox at all, you'll need to allow the skybox to draw in areas with a cleared depth value.

Comment: Oh I see, so if it was `GL_LESS` than it wouldn't be enough to pass the test.
So If I were to set the depth value of the skybox to `0.999f` it would be good to use `GL_LESS` I suppose?